# Embedded ARM with GCC - Is it okay for me to branch right to main() instead of going through mainCRTStartup?

Tags: arm, startup, newlib

I have some embedded ARM code compiled with GCC - and I want to get rid of the library startup files.

I looked at what Newlib's mainCRTStartup startup did, and although my ASM skills are terrible, it looks basically like stack setup, BSS clear and some constructor/destructor stuff.

I only use C, handle my own stack init, and can just clear BSS (although I think memory initialization takes care of that anyway). Can I just get rid of mainCRTStartup and branch right to main? What might I be missing?

Comment: Q: Can I use [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) without calling the Newlib initialization code in "mainCRTStartup"?  Q: Probably ... but I'd advise against it, until you  were confident "everything else was working", and unless you really, really know what you're doing  :(

Comment: if you are not using newlib, doing your own thing, then sure, do your own thing, minimal bootstrap/setup.  if you dont use .data and dont rely on .bss being zeroed (or have no globals or static locals) then all you really need is set the stack pointer and branch to the C entry point. That is how I normally operate.

Comment: I do use .data - but - newlib doesn't touch that anyway. The code manually copies that into RAM already.

Comment: was just a comment.  another comment is if this is a cortex-m then you can technically do without any bootstrap, just make a vector table (easiest using the assembler, but dont need instructions).

Comment: Can you tell me what about the cortex-m makes this so and what you mean by bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

This is not okay, you would probably need at least to copy the data and clear the bss.
But this can be done in C: the Cortex-M, like the Zilog z8000 in 1979, was designed so that no assembly boot code is required: the address of the first instruction to be executed will be loaded from vector address + 4, and the stack pointer will be loaded from vector address + 0.
Forcing an array of functions (`void *vector_table[]`) to reside at a specific section (`.isr_vector`) defined in the linker script will allow executing any startup code in C rather than in assembly language. All your initialization code can therefore be written in C.

The C example hereafter was written for an `stm32f103c8t6`, but can be easily adapted for any Cortex-M MCU.

linker script, `gcc_arm.ld`:

```
/* Linker script to configure memory regions. */
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
}

/* Library configurations */
/* GROUP(libgcc.a libc.a libm.a libnosys.a) */

/* Linker script to place sections and symbol values. Should be used together
 * with other linker script that defines memory regions FLASH and RAM.
 * It references following symbols, which must be defined in code:
 *   Reset_Handler : Entry of reset handler
 * 
 * It defines following symbols, which code can use without definition:
 *   __exidx_start
 *   __exidx_end
 *   __etext
 *   __data_start__
 *   __preinit_array_start
 *   __preinit_array_end
 *   __init_array_start
 *   __init_array_end
 *   __fini_array_start
 *   __fini_array_end
 *   __data_end__
 *   __bss_start__
 *   __bss_end__
 *   __end__
 *   end
 *   __HeapLimit
 *   __StackLimit
 *   __StackTop
 *   __stack
 */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)

        KEEP(*(.init))
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        /* .ctors */
        *crtbegin.o(.ctors)
        *crtbegin?.o(.ctors)
        *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .ctors)
        *(SORT(.ctors.*))
        *(.ctors)

        /* .dtors */
        *crtbegin.o(.dtors)
        *crtbegin?.o(.dtors)
        *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .dtors)
        *(SORT(.dtors.*))
        *(.dtors)

        *(.rodata*)

        KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.extab : 
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH

    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > FLASH
    __exidx_end = .;

    __etext = .;
        
    .data : AT (__etext)
    {
        __data_start__ = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* preinit data */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.preinit_array))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* init data */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP(*(.init_array))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);


        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* finit data */
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        KEEP(*(.fini_array))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* All data end */
        __data_end__ = .;

    } > RAM

    .bss :
    {
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        __bss_end__ = .;
    } > RAM
    
    .heap :
    {
        __end__ = .;
        end = __end__;
        *(.heap*)
        __HeapLimit = .;
    } > RAM

    /* .stack_dummy section doesn't contains any symbols. It is only
     * used for linker to calculate size of stack sections, and assign
     * values to stack symbols later */
    .stack_dummy :
    {
        *(.stack)
    } > RAM

    /* Set stack top to end of RAM, and stack limit move down by
     * size of stack_dummy section */
    __StackTop = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
    __StackLimit = __StackTop - SIZEOF(.stack_dummy);
    PROVIDE(__stack = __StackTop);
    
    /* Check if data + heap + stack exceeds RAM limit */
    ASSERT(__StackLimit >= __HeapLimit, "region RAM overflowed with stack")
}
```

`startup.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t __StackTop;
extern uint32_t __etext;
extern uint32_t __data_start__;
extern uint32_t __data_end__;
extern uint32_t __bss_start__;
extern uint32_t __bss_end__;

extern int  main(void);         // Application main entry point

#ifdef __USE_CMSIS
extern void SystemInit(void);   // CMSIS system initialization function
#endif //  __USE_CMSIS

void Reset_Handler(void) {
    uint32_t *src = &__etext;
    uint32_t *dst = &__data_start__;

    // Copying data section from flash to RAM.
    while (dst < &__data_end__) {
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }

    // Clearing the bss section.
    dst = &__bss_start__;
    while (dst < &__bss_end__) {
        *dst++ = 0;
    }

    // Calling CMSIS system initialization routine.
#ifdef __USE_CMSIS
    SystemInit();
#endif //  __USE_CMSIS

    // Calling application main entry point.
    main();

    // We should never return from main.
    for (;;);
}

void default_handler(void) {    // Default interrupt handler
    for (;;);
}

// cortex-m3 core interrupt handlers
void NMI_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void HardFault_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void MemManage_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void BusFault_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void UsageFault_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void SVC_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DebugMon_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void PendSV_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void SysTick_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));

// stm32f10x specific interrupt handlers
void WWDG_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void PVD_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TAMPER_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void RTC_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void FLASH_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void RCC_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI1_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void ADC1_2_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void USB_HP_CAN1_TX_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void USB_LP_CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM1_BRK_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM1_TRG_COM_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void SPI1_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void USART2_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void RTCAlarm_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));
void USBWakeUp_IRQHandler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("default_handler")));

// Interrupts vectors table
void *vector_table[] __attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector"))) = {
    &__StackTop,                // Top of Stack
    Reset_Handler,              // Reset Handler
    NMI_Handler,                // NMI Handler
    HardFault_Handler,          // Hard Fault Handler
    MemManage_Handler,          // MPU Fault Handler
    BusFault_Handler,           // Bus Fault Handler
    UsageFault_Handler,         // Usage Fault Handler
    0,                          // Reserved
    0,                          // Reserved
    0,                          // Reserved
    0,                          // Reserved
    SVC_Handler,                // SVCall Handler
    DebugMon_Handler,           // Debug Monitor Handler
    0,                          // Reserved
    PendSV_Handler,             // PendSV Handler
    SysTick_Handler,            // SysTick Handler

    // stm32f10x specific interrupt vectors
    WWDG_IRQHandler,            // Window Watchdog
    PVD_IRQHandler,             // PVD through EXTI Line detect
    TAMPER_IRQHandler,          // Tamper
    RTC_IRQHandler,             // RTC
    FLASH_IRQHandler,           // Flash
    RCC_IRQHandler,             // RCC
    EXTI0_IRQHandler,           // EXTI Line 0
    EXTI1_IRQHandler,           // EXTI Line 1
    EXTI2_IRQHandler,           // EXTI Line 2
    EXTI3_IRQHandler,           // EXTI Line 3
    EXTI4_IRQHandler,           // EXTI Line 4
    DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 1
    DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 2
    DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 3
    DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 4
    DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 5
    DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 6
    DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler,   // DMA1 Channel 7
    ADC1_2_IRQHandler,          // ADC1_2
    USB_HP_CAN1_TX_IRQHandler,  // USB High Priority or CAN1 TX
    USB_LP_CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler, // USB Low  Priority or CAN1 RX0
    CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler,        // CAN1 RX1
    CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler,        // CAN1 SCE
    EXTI9_5_IRQHandler,         // EXTI Line 9..5
    TIM1_BRK_IRQHandler,        // TIM1 Break
    TIM1_UP_IRQHandler,         // TIM1 Update
    TIM1_TRG_COM_IRQHandler,    // TIM1 Trigger and Commutation
    TIM1_CC_IRQHandler,         // TIM1 Capture Compare
    TIM2_IRQHandler,            // TIM2
    TIM3_IRQHandler,            // TIM3
    0,                          // Reserved
    I2C1_EV_IRQHandler,         // I2C1 Event
    I2C1_ER_IRQHandler,         // I2C1 Error
    0,                          // Reserved
    0,                          // Reserved
    SPI1_IRQHandler,            // SPI1
    0,                          // Reserved
    USART1_IRQHandler,          // USART1
    USART2_IRQHandler,          // USART2
    0,                          // Reserved
    EXTI15_10_IRQHandler,       // EXTI Line 15..10
    RTCAlarm_IRQHandler,        // RTC Alarm through EXTI Line
    USBWakeUp_IRQHandler,       // USB Wakeup from suspend
};
```

`main.c`:

```
void main()
{ 
    for (;;);
}
```

You could use a command similar to the one hereafter for compiling your code:
`/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -std=c99 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd  -Wall  -ggdb -MD -fmessage-length=0  -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-T gcc_arm.ld -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles startup.c main.c -o example.elf`

```
ll -gG *.elf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 70840 Jun 22 00:23 example.elf*
```

Comment: Yes, I corrected above. I am not 100% sure about  your question, is the answer relevant to it?

Comment: It is. I appreciate it. Primarily my question is "what magic is mainCRTStartup doing that I need". I think, for my use case nothing (I can clear bss, copy data set up stack myself). End-goal is I want to compile w/ -nodefaultlibs but the coupling to all the libraries seems to run deep :(

Comment: In this case,  would you consider accepting the answert ? thanks.